# How to get hidden URL value in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a column of URLs with hidden URL values (meaning that when you click on it you are redirected to the real website e.g. www.disney.com):

[image]

Cell example:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.example.com/go.php?website=128660","https://www.example.com/go.php?website=128660")
```

I need to visit each link manually to get the real URL and put it in the cell next to it.

What is the best way to automate this process?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. It might helpful to read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch

Answer (score 1):

Check [redirectnator](https://www.thetechseo.com/seo-tools/redirect-checker/)

[image]

Main purpose of the script is to check server code status but you can also look for the **final url**.

Here's the code

```
function redirectCheck(url, user, pwd) {
  try {
    function getResp(url, user, pwd){  
      var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        followRedirects: false,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user+':'+pwd)
        }
      });
      return resp;
    }

    var response = getResp(url, user, pwd);
    var rCode = response.getResponseCode();
    var redirectCount = 0;
    var tCode = rCode.toString();
    var location = url;
    var domain = getDomain(url);

    while (rCode == 301 || rCode == 302 && redirectCount <= 10) {
      redirectCount++;
      header = response.getHeaders();
      location = getFullUrl(header['Location'],domain);
      domain = getDomain(location);
      Logger.log('location: '+location);
      response = getResp(location, user, pwd);
      rCode = response.getResponseCode(); 
      tCode = tCode + " > " + rCode.toString();
      Utilities.sleep(500);// pause in the loop for 500 milliseconds
    }     


    Logger.log('redirectCount: '+redirectCount);
    return tCode + "|" + redirectCount + "|" + location;


  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return "Error| |"+error;
  }
}

function getDomain(url) {
  var domain = '',
      protocol;
  if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) {
    domain = url.split('/')[2];
    protocol = url.split('/')[0];    
    //remove port number
    domain = domain.split(':')[0];
    //add protocol back
    domain = protocol+"//"+domain;
  }  

  return domain;
}

function getFullUrl(url,prevDom) {
  var fullUrl,
      domain = getDomain(url);
  if(domain == ''){
    fullUrl = prevDom+url;
  } else {
    fullUrl = url;
  }       

  return fullUrl;
}

function redirectCheckTest() {
  var test = redirectCheck('www.google.com');
  Logger.log('test: '+test);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I need! But the next challenge is that my website requires login to redirect those links. I've tried "Username", "Password" fields provided by Redirectnator tool but it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an URL to share ? what tech the website is using ?

Answer (score -1):

Please use the following formula:

```
=IFNA(ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,".+\w+")))
```

*(adjust the range to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I wasn't clear enough in my question. Please have a look on the updated one.

Comment: I see your edit. So how could the sheet know which site the link redirects to? Is the real URL info anywhere in any cell?

Comment: There is no real info in the cell. I need to visit URL to get the real one.

Comment: *"I need to visit each link manually to get the real URL and put it in the cell next to it."*
**There is no other way.**  
That is the whole point of masking a URL. The masking action takes place on the server side, so you do have to click on the link.

Comment: I would suggest you re-edit your question to the original one, accept the answer and maybe post another question because what you ask by your edited one is completely different.